# Display Ajax loader before load data

Tags: ajax, jquery

Hello friends i want to show Ajax loader before Data load in particular div but problem is the data is coming dynamically on same page but my script calling data from another file  `Script.php` please see  my code below

**Script**

```
<script>
function loadingAjax(div_id)
{
    $("#"+div_id).html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif"> saving...');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "script.php",
        data: "name=John&id=28",
        success: function(msg){
            $("#"+div_id).html(msg);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<body onload="loadingAjax('myDiv');">


<div id="myDiv"></div>

<div id="xyz"><img src="ss/image/abc.jpg" /></div>


</body>
```

Its working fine but i want to load data in same page please help me

Thanks in advance ....

**EDIT**

I want to show loader before load data `#xyz` into `#myDiv`

Comment: What is the problem? you dont want to call ajax post data from other page or something else?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

you can try with following html -

```
<body onload="loadingAjax('myDiv');">
    <div id="myDiv">
        <img id="loading-image" src="ajax-loader.gif" style="display:none;"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

and the script -

```
<script>
function loadingAjax(div_id) {
      var divIdHtml = $("#"+div_id).html();
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "script.php",
           data: "name=John&id=28",
           beforeSend: function() {
              $("#loading-image").show();
           },
           success: function(msg) {
              $("#"+div_id).html(divIdHtml + msg);
              $("#loading-image").hide();
           }
      });
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you tick my answer if you found it useful?

Answer (score -2):

you can try with following script

```
<script>
function ajax()
{
    var options = {};
    options.url = '';
    options.type = 'post';
    options.data = '';
    options.dataType = 'JSON'; // type data get from sever
    options.contentType = 'application/json';// type data post to sever
    options.async = false;
    options.beforeSend = function () {

    };

    options.success = function (data)
    {

    };
    options.error = function (xhr, status, err) {

        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    };
    $.ajax(options);
}
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.