# Ajax download pdf file with large data

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to download large pdf file from server and server takes some time to generate pdf and respond so request showing as pending.

I need to show spinner when request starts and hide it when request is completed.

How can I accomplish this using JavaScript ASP.NET MVC.

**---UPDATE------**

Example controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile()
    {


        return File(@"C:\Temp2\HolidayInnReceipt.pdf", "application/pdf", "Report.pdf");

    }
```

**---UPDATE------**

[Here](https://app.box.com/s/0ljiki421zrc6jvma439poizfvjnualx) is sample project.

Answer (score 1):

## Add Below CSS

```
<style>
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 99;
    cursor: pointer;
}</style>
```

## In Form Tag

```
 <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" onclick="ConfirmDialog('Are you sure you want To Download?')">Download</button>
<br /><br />
<div id="overlay">
    <div id="text">
        <img src="~/assets/images/loadingimage.gif" style="width:5%;" /><span> &nbsp; Downloading....</span>
    </div>
</div>
<label class="error-msg" style="color:green;" itemid="lblmsg"></label>
```

## Script Tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ConfirmDialog(message) {
        debugger;

        var x = window.confirm(message)
        debugger;
        if (x) {
            on();               
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("YourMVC_Method", "Controller")',
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                success: function (result) {
                    debugger;
                    $("label[itemid='lblmsg']").show();
                    $('label[itemid="lblmsg"]').text('DownloadSuccess');
                    off();
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    //alert(ex);
                    $('label[itemid="lblmsg"]').hide();
                    off();
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $('label[itemid="lblmsg"]').hide();
            off();
        }
    }
    function on() {
        document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
    }

    function off() {
        document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It says file downloaded but no save as dialog opens in Chrome and I don't see file anywhere.

Comment: Simply Its Renaming all name actual code is import database Right!! You can only take on and off overlay method and ajax file for reference from my above code!! And  Set Your PDFs Download code!! It will working fine for u.. Thanks

Comment: In success: function (result) - result has the PDF file, how do I invoke browser default behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this using the Ajax request..

Step 1 Create ajax call to create pdf file
Step 2 Return saved pdf file path and set the window.location to download the pdf

At Step 1 -- you can show the spinner using the below approach:
[jQuery – AJAX Loading Effect: A Simple Way to Display Content Using AJAX Request](https://jqueryhouse.com/jquery-ajax-loading-effect-a-simple-way-to-display-content-using-ajax-request/)

**Example:**

```
   <body onload="loadingAjax('myDiv');">
    <div id="myDiv">
        <img id="loading-image" src="ajax-loader.gif" style="display:none;"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

and the script -

```
<script>
function loadingAjax(div_id) {
      var divIdHtml = $("#"+div_id).html();
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "controller/method", //URL which generate pdf
           data: "data here",
           beforeSend: function() {
              $("#loading-image").show();
           },
           success: function(msg) {
              $("#loading-image").hide();
              window.location= msg.FilePath;
           }
      });
}
</script>
```

**References:**
[Display Ajax loader before load data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515994/display-ajax-loader-before-load-data)

Comment: If you are returning json result which has property FilePath set with pdf file path

Comment: I am not returning JSON I am retiring FileResult which has inside file stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `URL.createObjectURL` to get temporary url for downloaded `blob` object then just use link with `download` attribute.

```
<div id="spinner" style="display: none;">Loading...</div>
<button onclick="downloadPDF()">Download</button>
```

```
function downloadPDF () {
  const spinner = document.getElementById("spinner")

  spinner.style.display = "block"

  fetch('YOUR_URL_HERE')
    .then(resp => resp.blob())
    .then(blob => {
      const href = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      const link = document.createElement('a')

      link.href = href;
      link.download = "filename.pdf"
      link.click()

      spinner.style.display = "none"
    })
}
```